# Make Pairwise array from comma separated string

Tags: php, arrays, string

Suppose I have a comma separated string like as follows:

```
1,Sunday,2,Monday,3,Tuesday,4,Wednesday,5,Thursday,6,Friday,7,Saturday
```

How can I make it an pairwise array in PHP like as follows --

```
array
(
  [1] => Sunday,
  [2] => Monday,
  [3] => Tuesday,
  [4] => Wednesday,
  [5] => Thursday,
  [6] => Friday,
  [7] => Saturday,
);
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Do you really need the commas in your array?

Comment: No I am not trying anything.But now I will try best of these suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer (requires PHP >= 5.5.0): if you don't need the trailing comma at the end of each value

```
$string = '1,Sunday,2,Monday,3,Tuesday,4,Wednesday,5,Thursday,6,Friday,7,Saturday';

$data = array_chunk(
    explode(',', $string),
    2
);
$newArray = array_combine(
    array_column($data, 0),
    array_column($data, 1)
);
var_dump($newArray);
```

If you do need the trailing comma, you can add:

```
array_walk(
    $newArray,
    function(&$value) {
        $value .= ',';
    }
);
```

Comment: I like your solution, especially because it doesn't require a loop! <3

Answer (score 1):

If you have such static data like weekdays and weekday numbers, it certainly would be the easiest to just use a static array:

```
$weekdays = array(
    1 => 'Sunday',
    2 => 'Monday',
    3 => 'Tuesday',
    4 => 'Wednesday',
    5 => 'Thursday',
    6 => 'Friday',
    7 => 'Saturday',
);
```

If you *have* to parse your comma separated string, you can use this:

```
$string = '1,Sunday,2,Monday,3,Tuesday,4,Wednesday,5,Thursday,6,Friday,7,Saturday';
$parts = explode(',', $string);
$weekdays = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts); ) {
    $weekdays[$parts[$i]] = $parts[++$i];
    ++$i;
}

print_r($weekdays);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Sunday
    [2] => Monday
    [3] => Tuesday
    [4] => Wednesday
    [5] => Thursday
    [6] => Friday
    [7] => Saturday
)
```

It ain't pretty, but it does the job :).

Comment: Good suggestion to have a static array in the first place

Answer (score 0):

This'll work for you.

```
$string = '1,Sunday,2,Monday,3,Tuesday,4,Wednesday,5,Thursday,6,Friday,7,Saturday.';
$dtd = explode(',', $string);
$array = array();
$i = 1;
foreach ($dtd as $key => $value){
    if($key % 2 == 1){
        $array[$i++] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($array);//Array ( [1] => Sunday [2] => Monday [3] => Tuesday [4] => Wednesday [5] => Thursday [6] => Friday [7] => Saturday. )
```